# How to do cusotm db query in controller? Zend 2

Tags: sql, zend-framework2

I wanto to sipmly iaterate the result in view. Problem is that it do not accually work. What is missing? I read the documentatnion but they do not give a full ansver how to retrieve data by cusotm query. For me as a beinnger is hard to understend what do next ? I mean about this query I know how to pass it to view by viewmodel et. Please Help.

```
$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');
$adapter = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($config[db]);
$sql = new Sql($adapter);
$select = $sql->select();
$select->from('brokerzy');
$select->where(array('broker_status' => 'publish'));
$stm = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
$results = $stm->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you probably shouldn't be doing queries in your controller, that's bad practice. These queries should be moved behind a service interface.

However, to answer your question (if I understand it), to pass the results of your query to a view, you should use a view model. It would look something like this.

```
//Your Code
$results = $stm->execute();

$viewModel = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
$viewModel->results = $results;
return $viewModel;
```